# When running my program on eclipse android real device i'm getting many errors in the LogCat what all this errors and how to fix them?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

On my smartphone I saw a message unfortunately the app has stopped.

Then I saw this errors in the LogCat:

```
07-19 14:32:48.438: D/ContextHelper(9232): convertTheme. context->name=com.example.texttospeechapp themeResourceId=2131427621
07-19 14:32:48.455: I/PhoneWindow(9232): [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
07-19 14:32:48.470: D/PhoneWindowEx(9232): [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
07-19 14:32:48.470: I/PhoneWindow(9232): [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
07-19 14:32:48.603: D/AndroidRuntime(9232): Shutting down VM
07-19 14:32:48.603: D/AndroidRuntime(9232): --------- beginning of crash
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232): Process: com.example.texttospeechapp, PID: 9232
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.texttospeechapp/com.example.texttospeechapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.texttospeechapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$OnInitListener
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.texttospeechapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$OnInitListener
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at com.example.texttospeechapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-19 14:32:48.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     ... 10 more
07-19 14:32:54.720: I/Process(9232): Sending signal. PID: 9232 SIG: 9
```

And this is my code in MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.texttospeechapp;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) this);
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        tts.speak("Text to say aloud", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors in my code. 9 warnings but no errors.

Solved: This is a working code:

```
package com.example.texttospeechapp;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnInitListener {


    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    TextToSpeech mTts;



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        //tts = new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        initTTS();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void initTTS() {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
        Intent installIntent = new Intent();
        installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE
                       || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
                             mTts.speak("Start system", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe more what you are doing. You are getting RunTime Exception. It's means it doesn't show error in your code. But in Run time.

Comment: Which warnings do you get? These are often a hint why a certain exception occurs; [Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine--mobile-8540) you can find sample code for usage of TTS, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==== **Problem** ====

You are getting a ClassCastException on this line of MainActivity:

```
    TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) this);
```

That is because you are casting `this`,  a reference to the activity, to a  OnInitListener.

By applying the cast, you have told the compiler that the `this` is an instance of OnInitListener.  That is why you do not get a compilation error.  The cast is however checked at runtime, and it fails when the VM determines `that` this is **not** an instance of that interface.  Thus the following LogCat message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.texttospeechapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$OnInitListener

==== **Solution** ====

To fix this you must implement that interface in your activity as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnInitListener {
```

and then you will need to implement the one OnInitListner method in your activity:

```
public void onInit (int status) {
   // This will be called when the text-to-speech engine has been initialized. 
}
```

Comment: EJK can you look at my question I added a small part of what I tried now. Changed the class MainActivity to the one with the OnInitListner and after that added the onInit method. And inside the onInit I added the TextToSpeech code. But getting same errors when running.

Comment: EJK did I do it right about the changes of the mainactivity and adding the onInit method ? And how should I initialized the text-so-speech engine I guess i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: EJK another strange thing the tts.speak so on speak I see line in black I see it also on the ActionBarActivity. What is this black line ?

Comment: I think you should move the contents of your onInit method to onCreate.

Comment: You need to start the TTS initialization early.  Do so in your activity's onCreate().  When the engine has initialized, your onInit() method will be called.  This is the point at which you can start using TTS.